# Need to know POST JSON Body Format for string and List<string> ormlite-servicestack

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I need the expertise help for JSON Body **FORMAT** for POST List and string. I have developed the JSON , C# web services by Service Stack. I would like to Post the List of 'Timestamp' along with String 'EmployeeId'. But at receiving end (Web Service) I am getting only string type 'EmployeeId'with
    List Timestamp is NULL. I have tried the number of ways as below.

Webservice Name:

```
http://192.168.1.109/EmployeeDatabase/json/reply/UpdateSyncStatus_EmployeeId_Timestamp

[Route("/UpdateSyncStatus_EmployeeId_Timestamp", "POST")]
public class UpdateSyncStatus_EmployeeId_Timestamp
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Timestamp { get; set; } 
}
```

I am Posting for test via Firefox HttpRequester utility.

The  BODY / Content in JSON format I have tried as below but nothing is working fine. I do not know where I am doing mistake:

1.

```
{"EmployeeId" : "gopsw_15_05_2015_17_17_571"},[{"Timestamp" : "2015-05-18T12:36:04.379"  ,  "Timestamp" : "2015-05-18T12:38:04.379" ,  "Timestamp" : "2016-05-18T12:38:04.379"}]
```

2.

```
{"EmployeeId" : "gopsw_15_05_2015_17_17_571"}, Timestamp : ["2015-05-18T12:36:04.379"  , "2015-05-18T12:38:04.379" ]
```

3.

```
{"EmployeeId" : "gopsw_15_05_2015_17_17_571"},[{"Timestamp" : "2015-05-18T12:36:04.379"} , {"Timestamp" : "2015-05-18T12:38:04.379"}]
```

4.

```
{"EmployeeId" : "gopsw_15_05_2015_17_17_571"},  "Timestamp" : [{"2015-05-18T12:36:04.379"} , {"2015-05-18T12:38:04.379"}]
```

5.

```
{"EmployeeId" : "gopsw_15_05_2015_17_17_571"},  {"Timestamp"} : [{"2015-05-18T12:36:04.379"} , {"2015-05-18T12:38:04.379"}]
```

6.

```
{"EmployeeId" : "gopsw_15_05_2015_17_17_571"},  {{"Timestamp"} : [{"2015-05-18T12:36:04.379"} , {"2015-05-18T12:38:04.379"}]}
```

Comment: Please put some effort in formatting your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Body that matches this Request DTO:

```
[Route("/UpdateSyncStatus_EmployeeId_Timestamp", "POST")]
public class UpdateSyncStatus_EmployeeId_Timestamp
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Timestamp { get; set; } 
}
```

Should look like:

```
POST /UpdateSyncStatus_EmployeeId_Timestamp

{"EmployeeId":"gopsw_15_05_2015_17_17_571","Timestamp":["2015-05-18T12:36:04.379","2015-05-18T12:38:04.379"]}
```

e.g. There's only 1 JSON Object (the entire DTO) and `Timestamp` is just an array of strings.

Whenever you're in doubt and want to know what the JSON should look like you can just serialize the object, e.g:

```
var json = new UpdateSyncStatus_EmployeeId_Timestamp {
    EmployeeId = "gopsw_15_05_2015_17_17_571",
    Timestamp = new []{"2015-05-18T12:36:04.379","2015-05-18T12:38:04.379"}.ToList()
}.ToJson();

json.Print();
```

Comment: Fantastic  Mythz its working fine. I have been strugling since morning but not able to fix it. Thank you very much for quick reply.